# Camera app using Android studio

Tags: android, webview, camera

i'm trying to create an app that instantly opens the camera app and takes a photo when pressing anywhere on the screen then searches the photo in google images. Please help it's for my senior project

Comment: Did you tried anything.. If not request you to try and post what issues you have in your attempt!

Comment: this is something i'm new in so i have no idea where to start so im getting all help i can get to begin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You can use (Material Camera) https://github.com/afollestad/material-camera to take a picture

2) CLOUD VISION API (https://cloud.google.com/vision/)
Tutorial (https://android.jlelse.eu/how-to-get-android-to-tell-if-your-beer-is-ok-yes-your-beer-a313b6c97a59#.raad9ktk6?utm_source=androiddevdigest)